# How can I work with multiple perforce client specs in TextMate?

Tags: macos, perforce, textmate, p4v

I am using [perfoce TextMate bundle](https://github.com/jondruse/perforce-tmbundle) to work with perforce from my TextMate editor. As far as I understood, you can only work with one client spec at a time. So I was wondering if anybody figured out a way to work with multiple client specs, without changing the P4CLIENT environment variable in TextMate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF your clientspecs checkout to a different location, try using the [P4CONFIG environment variable](http://perforce.com/perforce/doc.092/manuals/cmdref/env.P4CONFIG.html). Set it to something like .p4config and then place a .p4config in each of your root directories and it'll automatically pick up the settings specified in the file.